# date convert and merge in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have two sets of information.

One is a date that is in `Tuesday, January 26, 2010` format.
This is `$date`

Now i also have one of two things for time.
`$stime` can be either `7:30pm` or `Tuesday, January 26, 2010 7:30pm`

What i need to do, is first, convert `$stime` to `HH:MM:SS` format, then combine it with `$date` and convert the two together to `YYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$d = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$t = date('H:i:s', strtotime($stime));

$final = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $d . ' ' . $t);
```

very hacky.. but should work..

Comment: Was probably posted during my edit when the more correct solution dawned on me.  ;)

Comment: some dates are throwing crazy stuff like 1969-12-31 18:33:30

Comment: can you give me an example date?

Comment: some dates are throwing crazy stuff like 1969-12-31 18:33:30

Answer (score 3):

```
  date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('Tuesday, January 26, 2010 7:30pm'));
```

Or for the two separately:

```
 date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('$date $time'));
```

EDIT:
Actually, this should work, converting time first, then concatenating in the second line.:

```
   $time = date('H:i:s', strtotime('$time'));
   date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('$date $time'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the strtotime function to convert if for you, then you can use the date function to output it in the required format.  see the respective doc pages for the two functions.